# bitmap stream to video in c# howto?

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, stream

I have a code that receives a video stream through the webrtc library, which in its function shows them in a `PictureBox`, my question is .. how to pass that stream from the `PictureBox`to a video on my computer?

```
public unsafe void OnRenderRemote(byte* yuv, uint w, uint h)
{
    lock (pictureBoxRemote)
    {
        if (0 == encoderRemote.EncodeI420toBGR24(yuv, w, h, ref bgrBuffremote, true))
        {
            if (remoteImg == null)  
            {    
                var bufHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bgrBuffremote, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                remoteImg = new Bitmap((int)w, (int)h, (int)w * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, bufHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()); 
            }
        }
    }

    try
    {
        Invoke(renderRemote, this);
    }
    catch // don't throw on form exit
    {
    }
}
```

This code receives the stream through webrtc and converts it into images that are then shown in a `PictureBox`calling this function .. my question is:

How can I save an array or buffer of `remoteImg` images so I can write it to a video file on my pc?

Try doing something like this:

```
FileWriter.Open ("C:\\Users\\assa\\record.avi", (int) w, (int) h, (int) w * 3, VideoCodec.Default, 5000000);
FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame (remoteImg);
```

but only saves a single capture and not a video, is there any way to save the images of the stream with the `OnRenderRemote` function (described above) to be able to save them in a video?

`OnRenderRemote` only updates the `PictureBox` every time it is called, but I do not know how to save that flow in a video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: i do not know how the webrtc works exactly, but i can explain you how you must process the images to save them into a file.

Ok lets start: You currently have only full sized bitmaps of your own that are coming from the lib. That is just fine as long as you do not care about file size and you only want to show the "latest" frame. To store multiple frames into a file that we would call a "video" you need an encoder that processes those frames together.

Complicated things simple: An encoder takes 2 frames, call them Frame A and B and then compresses them in a way that only changes from Frame A to frame B are saved. This saves **a lot** of storage because in a video we only want to see "changes" aka movments from one frame to another. There are quite a lot of encoders out there but mostly you can see ffmpeg out there, its very popular and there are quite a lot c# wrappers for it so take a look.

Summery: to make 2-x images a "video" you have the process them with an encoder that processes the images in a format that can be played by a video player.